# lucas number with fibonacci

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I was trying to calculate a lucas number using fibonacci. So far I have:

```
const fibonacci = (n, a = 1, b = 0) => (n === 0) ? b : fibonacci(n - 1, a + b, a);
const lucas = (n) => (n - 1) + (n + 1);
lucas(fibonacci(7));
```

It worked with the number "3" so I thought I was all good but after testing I realized something was off.. I don't get it. Fibonacci works so why wouldn't taking the final value and make `Ln = F(n - 1) + F(n + 1)` ?

I'm relatively new to Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've really mistaken is to implement lucas serie itself. Your current lucas implementation just take an argument and sums its neigbours.

But what you should've done is,

```
const lucas = (f, n) => f(n-1) + f(n+1)
```

Because `lucas` function does not directly depend on the actual value of `n`, but value of a given `f(n)` (here f is fibonacci).

So, you've to pass that funcion explicitly to outer `lucas` function.

```
lucas(fibonacci, 7) /* fibonacci(6)+fibonacci(8) = 8 + 21 = 29 */
```

Comment: Thank you marmeladze! I have yet to call a function without () after it. This is a great learning experience. I also got it to work with your help thanks!